# Cross-referencing equation in MATLAB code for LaTeX Publishing

Tags: cross-referencing, matlab

I'm currently working with my team to write our capstone report. We need to use MATLAB code, and since we're using LaTeX to write our report, we also publish our code to LaTeX and include it in appendices.

Our prof wants a ton of comments in our MATLAB code. If we use an equation in MATLAB, we must reference the equation number from the body of the report.

The question is: Is there a way to use the label of an exisiting equation in our report (use \ref{eq:some_equation} in our MATLAB code) to automatically reference the equation number used? Here's a MWE:

**LaTeX Document**

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}

This is an equation that I will reference in MATLAB hopefully.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:relativity}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**MATLAB Code**

```
function test()

%% Appendix
% This is a test of referencing equations. See Equation
% \ref{eq:relativity}.
m = 1;
c = 3.0e8;
e = m*c^2;
```

**MATLAB LaTeX Publish used in original document above**

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is an equation that I will reference in Matlab hopefully.

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:relativity}
    E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\subsection*{Appendix}

\begin{par}
This is a test of referencing equations. See Equation   \ensuremath{\backslash}ref\{eq:relativity\}.
\end{par} \vspace{1em}
\begin{verbatim}
m = 1;
c = 3.0e8;
E = m*c^2;
\end{verbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
end
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

**Screenshot of PDF**
The output generated by pdflatex shows:
[image]

whereas obviously, I want the equation number to show up instead of `\ref{eq:relativity}`

**UPDATE:** I tried `<latex>\ref{eq:relativity}</latex>` which which was published to

```
\begin{verbatim}latex\end{verbatim}\ensuremath{\backslash}ref\{eq:relativity\}\ensuremath{<}/latex\ensuremath{>}
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `See Equation~\ref{eq:relativity}.`?

Comment: @yudai-nkt He does, but the problem is that Matlab changes it to `\ensuremath{backslash}ref\{..\}` when exporting.

Comment: Can you try `<latex>\ref{eq:relativity}</latex>`, c.f. https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html#btga6k2-3

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Got it, I didn't understand the problematic part was generated by MATLAB export. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That was a great idea, but it didn't work... The publish output was\begin{verbatim}latex\end{verbatim} \ensuremath{\backslash}ref\{eq:relativity\} \begin{verbatim}/latex\end{verbatim}.

Comment: The essential problem is that comments, both in MATLAB and LaTeX, are not supposed to be variable.  You would need a separate program to modify the source code.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That sounds about right... I was hoping there would be an easy work around. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the conversion to work properly, you need to a bit careful about where to place the `<latex>`/`</latex>` tags: there cannot be any text on the line either before or after it. That of course makes problems if you only want to place the `\ref` in that tag, as you'd have to do

```matlab
% This is a test of referencing equations. See Equation
%
% <latex>
% \ref{eq:relativity}.
% </latex>
%
```

which would output

```latex
This is a test of referencing equations. See Equation

\ref{eq:relativity}.
```

So instead, write the entire paragraph in the `latex` tag:

```matlab
function test()

%% Appendix
%
% <latex>
% This is a test of referencing equations. See Equation~\ref{eq:relativity}.
% </latex>
%
m = 1;
c = 3.0e8;
e = m*c^2;
```

Again, the empty (commented) lines before it is important, either of these wont work:

```matlab
% foo
% <latex>
% This is a test of referencing equations. See Equation~\ref{eq:relativity}.
% </latex>
%
% 
% <latex>
% This is a test of referencing equations. See Equation~\ref{eq:relativity}.
% </latex>
% foo
```

## Addendum

I noted that by default every paragraph will be marked up like this:

```latex
\begin{par}    
Text in the paragraph.    
\end{par} \vspace{1em}
```

The `\begin{par}` and `\end{par}` are probably intended as counterparts to `<p>` and `</p>` in HTML, and the `\vspace` is to separate paragraphs, but this is rather odd.

Luckily, it is possible to customize the kind of code Matlab produces. The template that decides this is found in an `.xsl` file called `mxdom2latex.xsl`. On my system it's found in

```bash
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/toolbox/matlab/codetools/private/mxdom2latex.xsl
```

I assume the path will be similar on other systems. You can make a copy of it and edit it. Then in the publishing options, you can select this `.xsl` file:

[image: matlab publishing options]

So what kind of edits should one do. The `\begin{par}` stuff mentioned above is defined in lines 105-109 (at least in my version). Modify those lines to

```xsl
<xsl:template match="p">
<xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text>

</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

From your question I take it that you're including this code in a different document, so that would mean you don't want the `\documentclass`, preamble and the `document` environment. The preamble is written verbatim in lines 24-32, and `\end{document}` on line 82, all of which can be removed from the custom `.xsl` file.

Matlab also generates a list of contents, if you don't want that, you can remove lines 90-98 (line 90  has `\subsection*{Contents}`, line 98 has `\end{itemize}`).

Having removed all of that, if you've published `somefunc.m` into `somefunc.tex`, then you can do `\input{somefunc}` in your main document.

(I'd post the entire edited `.xsl` file, but I'm not sure whether that's OK to do, license wise. That said, simple modifications like these are fairly easy to figure out, even though I don't really know anything about XSL.)

Comment: Ideally you should make a custom `.xsl` file to remove the ridiculous `\begin{par} .. \end{par} \vspace{1em}`. I might get back to that later.

Comment: I am not familiar with `.xsl` files, so if you feel like helping me out, go for it, but obviously I'm not expecting it, as what you answered works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jonathan.charbonneau I added some description of it, and it might be of interest to other people seeing it as well, I suppose.

Comment: That is wonderful! Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!